# Why “Toggle Sidebar” button is not visible on small devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

Reading this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#utilities docs
I try in Bootsrap 4.1 app to show “Toggle Sidebar” button only on small and extrasmall devices, and I do

```
    <div class="d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none ">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light   ">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fa fa-align-left" style="color: white"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    @yield('content')
</div>
```

But it does not work for small devices : it is not visible, on all the rest devices works as expected
I tried to add d-sm-block class :

```
    <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none ">
```

But it does not work anyway...

Which is the right way?

Comment: Why are you using both the display classes and the responsive navbar? Is this a Navbar?

Comment: That is a button to toggle navbar. I show link at the example I use this navbar. Which of the class defininition have I to remove ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add d-none to hidden in xl and d-sm-block 
this code will display button in sm screen only

```
<div class="d-md-none d-lg-none d-none d-sm-block ">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light   ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                <i class="fa fa-align-left" style="color: white"></i>
                <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

if you need to display it on small and extrasmall you can write

```
<div class="d-md-none d-lg-none d-sm-block ">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light   ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                <i class="fa fa-align-left" style="color: white"></i>
                <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but none of your 2 examples is visible at all